# missing header when building eudev 3.2.7

Tags: linux, buildroot

I am using buildroot to build code.
When it come to eudev, it show some error

```
ata_id.c:35:10: fatal error: scsi/scsi.h: No such file or director
```

But I can find this header in

```
buildroot/dl/linux/git/drivers/scsi/scsi.h
buildroot/dl/linux/git/include/scsi/scsi.h
buildroot/output/build/linux-headers-master/drivers/scsi/scsi.h
```

Any idea or hint?

Comment: I'm not very experienced in Buildroot, but for me in some cases there is need to run `make clean all` instead of pure `make`. Unfortunately, you will wait until all packages will be rebuilt. Look at 8.2 in https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#full-rebuild

Comment: @BigDongle Did you have any success on this? I'm facing the very same problem

Comment: @MuhammedB.Aydemir make clean all as the manual